# How do I get the URL to be able to pass it to the activity

Tags: java, android, url, hashmap

I have my code as follows

```
// Hashmap for ListView
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> appealsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           TextView urlTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url);     
           String url = urlTv.getText().toString();
           url = appealsList.get("url");

           for(HashMap map: appealsList){
               url = map.get(key);
           }
           //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LaunchReadMoreActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("url", url);
           //intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
           startActivity(intent);
}

});
```

appealsList contains date, title, url obtained from JSONarray
my URL is always empty?

How do I extract the url string from the appealsList.

I don't want to iterate the list but if user clicks anywhere in the list ie any record in the list I should be able to pick the url for that object in the list.

This is how I got it to work:

```
   //TextView urlTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url);     
   //String url = urlTv.getText().toString();
   String url = appealsList.get(position).get("url");              
   //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LaunchReadMoreActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("url", url);
   //intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: appealsList.get(position).get("url"); position will give the index of the item in arraylist. and then you get the value from the map useing the key url.

Comment: are you using an adapter?

Comment: @User111 can you show how you added the values to the arraylist? If the key does not match it will return null.

Comment: @User111 you can mark the answer now by clicking the tick once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this code even works. How can you call `appealsList.get("url")` when the `appealsList` is an `ArrayList`? Try maybe `appealsList.get(position).get("url")`

Answer (score 1):

`appealsList.get(position).get("url");` position will give the index of the item in `ArrayList` and then you can get the value from the map by using the key value "url".

For example:

Try out below code inside your ListView item click listener:

```
  String myurl = appealsList.get(position).get("url").toString();
```